# Jackson preprocess json before sending to deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON string which I would like to translate into POJO using `ObjectMapper.readValue` method.

The thing is that the input Json string contains keys which I would like to filter out before the deserialization.

I came across `DelegatingDeserialization` class which according to my understanding allows you to extend it and override one of the `deserialize` method to reconstruct the json input and then pass it on the chain.

The thing is that I try to enable this custom delegating deserializer by adding the
`@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDelegatingDeserialization.class)` on top of my Pojo - is that the right way to instantiate it??

Here is a snippet of my custom delegator:

```
  public static class CustomDeserializer extends DelegatingDeserializer {

    public CustomDeserializer() {
      super(null);
    }

    public CustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) {
      super(defaultDeserializer);
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegatingInstance(JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegatee) {
      return new CustomDeserializer(newDelegatee);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
      return super.deserialize(restructure(p), ctxt);
    }

    private JsonParser restructure(JsonParser jp) throws IOException {

     ...
      return newJsonParser;
   }
}
```

Am I taking the right path or there is a more fitting solution??

THank you!

**EDIT 1**

Another approach is to have a `CustomJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<T>` and override its `deserialize` method then reconstruct the `Node` and propagate it by returning `codec.treeToValue(jsonNode, Pojo.class);` this makes sense **BUT** it gets me into infinite loop! any idea why?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your JSON and specify what keys you want to skip?

Comment: `{ "A" : ["A", "AA", AAA"], "B":["B", "BB", "BBB"], "ZZ":"ZZZZZ"}

I would like to get rid of `ZZ` key so my Pojo would be deserialized into a Map<String, List<String>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your POJO doesn't have a property that you would like to ignore you can use annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`for your class. That tells Jeckson to ignore properties that are not present in your POJO. Read more on the issue how to ignore some properties here: [Jackson Unmarshalling JSON with Unknown Properties](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties)